# Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3 JAVA Statement gets deleted

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

Having trouble with the editor.

There must be some feature that is automatically deleing statements that appear erred (regardless of whether the erred statement(s) are typed in or pasted in).

I tried pasting statements like this one (below) at the top, and my lines seems to appear pasted into the code for half a second, before it disappears--probably because the path can't be recognized.  So I am wondering why it is doing that, instead of underlining it in red, and giving an error message.  How do I change this behavior?

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called "Optimize imports on the fly". The import statement is deleted because it is unused. You can use the settings search to find the setting for this feature and turn it off.

However, rather than pasting the import statements manually, the recommended approach is to leave the feature enabled and to let IntelliJ IDEA manage the imports for you automatically.